# Need advice on choosing free angularjs charting library which also works offline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, diagram, angular-chart

I need free angularjs library which provides various charts and works offline

I have already found angular-chart which looks most used charting library, but cannot find any info if it works offline.

1) Does anyone know if i can use angular-chart offline ?

2) Are there any better or easier to use libraries for charting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[D3](https://d3js.org/) is a pretty popular JavaScript data visualization library. You can check out [Angular-nvD3](https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) which is a directive based on D3 (and [nvD3](http://nvd3.org/), which is a project that has re-usable components). It might not be easier, but it's definitely robust.